# Formula to extract only unique values from horizontal range into a single cell, separated by comma

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

I have a spreadsheet where users are asked to place a value in their allocated column across many rows.

There are a range of other columns used by an Admin area and one of these is supposed to list only the unique values entered by users in the corresponding row.

EXAMPLE DATA

[image]

So, using the above screenshot as an example:

- users are allocated a column to complete (e.g. column K) in which they need to enter a value such as I, R, C etc down a number of rows.
- the Admin area needs to summarise these in another column by indicating all of the unique values for that row, separated by comma (e.g. in Cell I9 they would enter I, R, C).

I've been asked to automate this in some way so that the Admin area doesn't have to manually identify the unique values for each row and enter them in. At present the best I have come up with is the following approach:

- In a later column (Let's say Cell AA9) I am using the UNIQUE function as follows: `=UNIQUE(K9:O9,1)`. This then populates the following cells with each of the unique values in the range, only once. That is, AA9 will have I, AB9 has R, AC9 has C and so on.
- In Cell I9 I use a formula as follows: `=K9&", "&L9&", "&M9&", "&N9&", "&O9`

This does achieve the desired result (although it does show a zero (0) value for any blank cells, which is annoying), but to my mind there would have to be a more elegant way to achieve this.

**Question**

Is there a way to have a single formula in Cell I9 that does the job of both formulas I'm using (i.e. it does the job of both what's in AA9 and I9 at present), returning all of the unique values in I9 separated by comma and without the need to use helper columns at AA, AB etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle the problem of multiple, comma-separated entries in a single cell, try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,K27:N27),",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(preceding-sibling::* = .)]"))
```

**Algorithm**

- Join the cells with a comma separator
- Create an `XML` for each comma-delimited substring
- Use an `xPath` which only returns the unique nodes
- Join the results of the `FILTERXML` function with a comma delimiter

*There are other solutions if you have a Mac and do not have the `FILTERXML` function*

[image]

If necessary, you could SORT the results

***Edit for MAC Office 365 solution***

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,K27:N27),",",REPT(" ",99)),IF(SEQUENCE(99,,0)=0,1,SEQUENCE(99,,0)*99),99))))
```

Comment: Very good answer +1.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Please undelete your original answer. It still solves the problem except for instances of multiple values in a single cell. I feel it would definitely be useful for others and would like to give it an upvote.

Comment: Thanks Ron, this does the trick. :) If at all possible, could you shed light on what a Mac solution would be? We also use Macs (although for this context we're using Windows PCs), but to be thorough it would make your answer even better and apply to more users. Thanks again!

Comment: @Monomeeth MAC sol'n posted, but it does require Office 365

Comment: Thanks Ron, that's awesome. Appreciate you taking the time to come back and add the edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `TEXTJOIN` function with your `=UNIQUE(K9:O9;1)`

```
=TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;UNIQUE(K9:O9;1))
```

Change the `;` to `,` as you use a different regional setting to mine.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I did have a play with using `TEXTJOIN` earlier but couldn't work out how to have the end result only showing each unique value once? Likewise with your example. In both cases I can't work out why, but, if you can show me how to correct that, then that'd be exactly what I need. Just to clarify my meaning, referring back to the screenshot in my question, the end result in I9 should be I, R, C, **not** I, I, R, C, I.

Comment: @Monomeeth The values `I,I,R,C,I` as from the range K9 to O9 not the final result. The final result is on I9: `I,R,C`. Look closely at the screenshot.

Comment: I think I just worked out what the problem is. In some cases users enter multiple values in the one cell. So, looking at my screenshot again, and specifically at row 11, the formula returns `l,C,R,I,C`, but now I see that that's because cell K11 has `I,C` entered in it, so the formula **is** working, it's just unfortunate in this scenario that it's seeing `I,C` in Cell K11 as a different value unique from the `I` in cells M11 and O11 and from the `C` in N11. So, all this time I thought I was going crazy, but it wasn't until your last comment that I realised *what* was going on! Thanks! :)

Comment: I don't suppose you can think of any way to *fix* that situation?

Comment: @Monomeeth Do the users enter at most 2 values in one cell like in K11 with `I,C`?

Comment: In total there are four possible options: R, A, C and I. But, I've taken a look and so far I can't find an example of where someone has entered more than 2 values in a single cell. So, while I guess it's possible that someone at some point could enter 3 or 4 values, it seems that allowing for two would do the job.